# Cannot get count of feedburner subscribers

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, feedburner

I'm trying to run this code:

```
public string FeedReadersCount(string id)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=" + id);
    return (from item in xdoc.Descendants("entry")
            select item.Attribute("circulation").Value).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

but it returns 404 error. Does anybody know an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The Feedburner API was deprecated as of Oct. 20, 2012. I'm trying to figure out another way to get the subscriber count as well.